# Insertar registros en tabla mysql mediante Sentencias preparadas

Tags: php, mysql

Adjunto el código que lee de una tabla y escribe en otra determinados campos, el tema es que seguí los ejemplos que vi en Stacoverflow... y no me da resultado, si bien aparece la leyenda de registro grabado, no graba nada. Alguna sugerencia?

```
foreach($emails as $email) {

    echo $email['mail'];

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO mailing (id, mail, nombre, telefono, estado) VALUES (null, :mail, :nombre, :telefono, :estado)");

    $statement->execute(array(
    ':mail' => $email['mail'],
    ':nombre' => $email['nombre'],
    ':telefono' => '',
    ':estado' => '1'
    ));

    echo " - Grabado"."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo usualmente lo hago de este modo, lo que debes haces es capturar el posible error, ya que ese `echo grabo` siempre se ejecutara haya habido un error o no, ya que no hay nada que lo condiciones, siemplemente esta el el flujo de ejecucion.

```
<?php 



    echo $email['mail'];

    $email=$email['mail'];
    $nombre=$email['nombre'];
    $telefono='';
    $estado=1;


    $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO mailing (mail, nombre, telefono, estado) VALUES (:mail, :nombre, :telefono, :estado)");
    //pasas los parametros de forma indidual
    $statement->bindParam(':mail', $email);
    $statement->bindParam(':nombre', $email);
    $statement->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
    $statement->bindParam(':estado', $estado);
    //preguntas si la sentencia fue bien recibida
    if ($statement ->execute();) {
      echo " - Grabado"."<br>";
    }
    else{ //si con esto sabras que hubo un error
      echo " - Algo Fallo! Revisar la BD"."<br>";
    }
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas como te fue:

Comment: @Ricardo Pastuszek entonces haz un insert directamente desde tu motor de base de datos, y mejor aun muestrame como esta la estructura de BD y la tabla a la que haces referencia, quizas hay algun campo que requiere y lo estas mandando null, y otra cosa, si vas a mandar null en el id es mejor que no lo pongas.

Comment: no comprendo a lo que te refieres con que no ponga lo de id?.... porque en todos lados esta indicado como que debo ingresar NULL

Comment: Respecto a la tabla:
id           in(11)               autoincrementable    Indice primario //
mail       varchar(100) indice //
nombre  varchar (100) // 
telefono varchar100) // 
estado   tinyint(1) //

Comment: son solo esos campos ? por eso si el ID es auto incrementable no lo llames, deja que el automaticamente te cambia el valor, es decir si no le mandas nada el igual lo hara

Comment: Tu dices que la linea de la consulta quede de la siguiente forma?: 
`$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO mailing (mail, nombre, telefono, estado) VALUES (:mail, :nombre, :telefono, :estado)"); `

Comment: Sigue sin grabar.... creo tomare alguna pastilla para el corazon...

Comment: Asi funciono el insert en la bd:

`set @mail = 'claromeconet@gmail.com', @nombre = 'Ricardo', @telefono = '', @estado = '1';
INSERT INTO `mailing` (`id`, `mail`, `nombre`, `telefono`, `estado`) VALUES (NULL, @mail, @nombre, @telefono, @estado)`

Comment: y asi un sigue teniendo la funcionalidad de preparadas

Comment: Eso fue una insersión manual desde el motor de base de datos, pero he ingresado una función para que me detecte el error y el mismo es:

""Duplicate entry 'rapastusze@gmail.com' for key 'mail' "" con el primer registro a grabar y asi con todo el resto, por consiguiente no hay datos en la base, como es que me duplica la clave?